# how to round to nearest 50 or 100?

Tags: java, groovy

I have numbers (in decimal) I want to round it to "nearest 50":

1. 122 => round to 150
2. 177 => round to 200
3. 157 => round to 200
4. 57 => round to 100;
5. 37 => round to 50;
6. 1557 => round to 1600
7. 3537 => round to 3550

how to do that with java/groovy ?

Comment: How would you know that, 57 rounds to 100 and not 50?

Comment: Do you mean round _up_ to the nearest 50?

Comment: `x + (50 - (x % 50))`

Comment: @IsmailBadawi sorry, this fails if `x` is already a multiple of 50.  (I'm assuming that the answer is supposed to be `x` in that case.)

Comment: `50 * ((x + 49) / 50)`

Comment: Note for others: "nearest X" can mean "round down or up" but also "only round up". In this case, rounding up is meant by OP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Groovy `x + (50 - (x % 50 ?: 50))` :

```
def round50up = { int x ->
    x + ( 50 - ( x % 50 ?: 50 ) )
}

assert round50up( 122  ) == 150 
assert round50up( 177  ) == 200 
assert round50up( 157  ) == 200 
assert round50up( 57   ) == 100 
assert round50up( 37   ) == 50 
assert round50up( 1557 ) == 1600 
assert round50up( 3537 ) == 3550 
assert round50up( 100  ) == 100 
assert round50up( 200  ) == 200 
assert round50up( 250  ) == 250
```

Test it [<kbd>**here**</kbd>](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5699127396532224).

Answer (score 7):

I believe djechlin's solution is almost right, he just left out some parts.

(x+49)/50 * 50;

This works, because in Java, the result of integer division is an integer (the result is truncated). To explain for me, here are your examples with an additional example for a number which is already a multiple of 50:

```
122   + 49 => 171   / 50 => 3   * 50 => 150
177   + 49 => 226   / 50 => 4   * 50 => 200
157   + 49 => 206   / 50 => 4   * 50 => 200
57    + 49 => 106   / 50 => 2   * 50 => 100
37    + 49 => 86    / 50 => 1   * 50 => 50
1557  + 49 => 1606  / 50 => 32  * 50 => 1600
3537  + 49 => 3586  / 50 => 71  * 50 => 3550
150   + 49 => 199   / 50 => 3   * 50 => 150
```

Comment: if i enter x = 150 it will round up to 199 ... which is not correct. it should stay at 150

Comment: @nightingale2k1 It works, look at the last line. It adds 49 to get 199. Then it does integer division by 50 to get 3. Then it multiplies by 50 to get 150, the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

Hi I made this script for you

```
function roundToNearest(x) {
    if (x%50 < 25) {
        return x - (x%50); 
    }
    else if (x%50 > 25) {
        return x + (50 - (x%50)); 
    }
    else if (x%50 == 25) {
        return x + 25; //when it is halfawy between the nearest 50 it will automatically round up, change this line to 'return x - 25' if you want it to automatically round down
    }        
}

console.log(roundToNearest(701));
```

I tested it and it successfully rounds to the nearest 50, u can run it here to test it.

http://repl.it/languages/JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

To round to the nearest 50 (up or down). you can convert to float divide by the amount you want to round into, use Math.round then multiply back up:

```
    int orgVal = 122;
    Math.round((float)orgVal/50f)*50;
```

This only rounds, if you want to raise it to the next 50 which matches your examples, you can do the same thing but use the Math.ceil method

```
    int orgVal = 122;
    (int)Math.ceil((float)orgVal/50f)*50;
```

Answer (score 2):

`(x+25)/50*50`

My answer is too short because I actually posted the simplest way to do this, so you also get this sentence.

Edit: I'm answering the question you asked, not what your examples illustrate. Leaving this answer in case anyone else has your question and tries to read the answers.

Comment: x = 122 => (122 + 25) / 50 = 2.94 (quite different from the expected 150)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt the OP said "round to the nearest 50", and djechlin said he was answering the question the OP asked, not the question implied by the OP's examples.  So the expected result would be 100, not 150, under that assumption.  The actual result is 2, not 2.94, because he's assuming `x` is an integer and therefore `/` is integer division.  But @djechlin did leave something important out...

Comment: @ajb I wouldn't have commented on an outcome of "100". But 2.94 is a bit off (not sure where you get the "2" from, the OP nor the answer specifies a datatype like `int` or `double`) Given the other answers, I don't think this that this one adds much, especially as it omits the  "times `x`" step.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt all of the examples were integers. `122` is an integer literal in Java. `122L` is a long, `122.0` is a double and `122.0f` is a float.

Comment: @ajb what did I leave out? it's not great for future visitors to see an answer that is complete except mysteriously missing something I did wrong.

Comment: Your interpretation of the question is that if `x`=122, the result should be `100` (rounded to the nearest 50).  The expression you posted will yield `2`, not `100`.  Didn't you leave out `50 *`?

Answer (score 1):

You're rounding to the nearest multiple of 50 or 100 i might think. Try:

x is your input.

```
int roundTo = 0; // this will serve as the value to round off to  
if(x%50 == 0){
 roundTo = x; // do nothing as x is already a multiple of 50
}
else{
roundTo = ((x/50) + 1) * 50; 
}
```

then use this to get the rounded value:

```
x = x + (roundTo - x);
```

example:

```
x is 49;
roundTo = 50 // (49/50 +1) * 50
x = 49 + (50 - 49)
x = 50

  x = 160
 roundTo = 200 // (160/50 + 1) * 50
 x = 160 + (200 - 160)
 x = 160
```

Answer (score 1):

Here`s in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    System.out.println(round_to_nearest_50(**yournumber**)); // put there your number

}

private static int round_to_nearest_50(int number) { // just keep this method
    int ergebnis = number;
    if (number % 50 == 0) {}
    else if (number % 50 < 25) { ergebnis -= 50 - number % 50; }
    else if (number % 50 >= 25) {ergebnis += 50 - number % 50; }
    return ergebnis;
}
```