# Easiest way to round down to nearest 50 or 00

Tags: php

i want to round up a number like this

```
1439 to 1400
1399 to 1350
```

What are the nearest way to do this in php?

Comment: $number = 1439;
$sum = round($number/50);
echo $sum*50; only round to 50 not 00

Comment: Your title says you want to round to nearest 50, but your question puts 1450 to 1500. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to round to nearest 50 or 100?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438203/how-to-round-to-nearest-50-or-100)

Comment: @hkguile Well, you've completely changed the question with no explanation.. invalidating all the answers. I'm guessing you want to round DOWN to the nearest 50!

Comment: sorry , this question should be round down to nearest 50 / 00

Comment: This is a joke. "I want to round up", yet you round down. If you want serious answers (and are too lazy to do some search for the dozens of existing answers), then at least put *some* effort into making your question meaningful. Or was it *nearest*? How is 1350 the the nearest from 1399?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like that (only to round down) :

```
$n1 = 1439;
$n2 = 1399;

$round1 =  $n1 -  $n1 % 50; // round1 = 1439 - 39 = 1400
$round2 =  $n2 - $n2 % 50; // round2 = 1399 - 49 = 1350
```

To round up, you can do this :

```
$n1 = 1439;
$n2 = 1399;

$round1 =  $n1 + (50 -  $n1 % 50); // round1 = 1439 + (50 - 39) = 1450
$round2 =  $n2 + (50 - $n2 % 50); // round2 = 1399 + (50 - 49) = 1400
```

Answer (score 7):

*Given the new examples...*

Looks like you want to use [PHP floor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) instead and apply the 50 yourself

```
50 * floor($number / 50)
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

*Going from your examples, rather than the question title..*

Try the [PHP round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function.

In your case:

```
round($number, -2);
```

The second param is the number of decimal figures to round to, negative values go to the left of the 'ones' digit instead.

There is also a third parameter for some more subtle variations.

Comment: think should be -2, because from doc - echo round(1241757, -3); // 1242000

Comment: @degr Good spot! Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

```php
$rounded_n1 = round($n1 / 50, 0) * 50;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like:

1. Divide it by 100.
2. Truncate.
3. Multiply by 100.

This is the best thing I could come up with.

```
$num = 1401;
$num /= 100;
$num = round($num);
$num *= 100;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be 50?

Comment: @Eiko 50? How?? It's 1500.

Comment: Did you read the title of the question? Doesn't make sense with the example given, though - as I stated in the comments.

Comment: @Eiko Just saw it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should try:

```
    function specialRoundUp($val) {
      return 100 * round($val / 100);
    }
```

Comment: This function matches your example. If you really wanted to round to nearest 50 or 00, then the examples are wrong and two last should round to 1450. It should be changed to: `return 50 * round($val / 50);`

Answer (score 2):

Use ceil to always round up

```
$round1 = ceil($n1/ 50) * 50
```